# In python constructor runs on compile time or run time?

Tags: python-3.x, compile-time

python constructor initializes when it it instantiated . I want to know instantiated runs on which time and constructor runs on which time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors in python run to initialize objects. Objects are created at runtime, so constructors run at runtime. No code is executed at compile time in python.

Comment: So instantiation of a class and object same